# Problems with extra Contact names in Emails

Tags: mail.app, email, contacts

When I want to send an email to a specific group, I open Contacts, highlight the Group name, select everyone in that group, and then either drag or copy and paste those names into the To: or Bcc: field in Mail (If there is an easier way to do this, I'd LOVE to hear about it.)
Recently, when I do this, a random person from other contact groups gets added multiple times in the To: or Bcc: field. It's always someone different and I can't find why this is happening. I end up having to go through the To: of Bcc: list and manually delete each time the person's address shows up.
Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get more info from [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25887?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US).  If you follow these steps, you shouldn't have the problem of someone different showing-up in one of the fields.

Create a new email message to the group directly from **Contacts**.

- Do one of the following:

  1. <kbd>Control</kbd>-click a group in the sidebar, then choose `Send Email`. A new email opens in the Mail app, addressed to the group.
  2. Drag a group from the sidebar to an address field in an email you’re writing.

[image]

In your email, either the group name or individual contact names are shown, depending on how Composing preferences are set in Mail.

If the group is shown in your email but you want to see the contacts instead, click the arrow next to the group name, then choose `Expand Group`.

[image]

**Tip**: When you’re addressing an email, you can see all the available addresses for a contact by clicking the arrow next to their name. To email the contact using more than one of their addresses, copy and paste their name, click the arrow, then choose another address.